# React Component with multiple child components

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React, but the tutorials I have followed mostly stick with using a single component or multiple different components. Moving from these tutorials to build my React application, I realized that I can't find a good example on inheritance. I did read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) from the documentation which seems to focus more on adding functional components, which is different from what I am doing. My question here, is for guidance to check if my approach isn't something that will shoot me in the foot later or there is a better way.

I am using a traditional class based component structure. My parent component follows below. This code block connects to my node server to render a basic form that is prefilled with data from the server. The submitHandler then updates the server.

```
class StandardComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.submitHandler = this.submitHandler.bind(this)
    }

    // Connect to the server
    callBackendApi = table_name => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const response = await fetch(`./api/list_all?table=${table_name}`)
            const body = await response.json()

            if (response.status !== 200) {
                reject(body.errorMessage);
            } else {
                resolve(body.message)
            }
        })
    }

    // Check component mounted
    async componentDidMount() {
        const table_headers = this.state.table_headers
        const data = table_headers.map(table_name => {
            return this.callBackendApi(table_name)
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        })

        // Resolve promises and update state
        Promise.all(data).then(results => this.setState({data: results, initial_loading_screen: false}))
    }

    async submitHandler(event) {
        const table_headers = this.state.table_headers
        const table_columns = GetColumnNames(this.state.data)
        const raw_page_data = GetPageData(event, table_columns)

        await SendPageData(raw_page_data, table_headers, table_columns, '/api')

        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return <InitialRender />
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet of one of my classes that inherit my parent class. I use this class to render my page.

```
class Content extends StandardComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // API request
            data: null,
            table_headers: ['resume_header', 'resume_skills', 'resume_experience', 'resume_education'],

            // Check loading state
            initial_loading_screen: true,
            hasPageLoaded: null,

            // Errors
            hasError: false,
        }

        this.submitHandler = this.submitHandler.bind(this)
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.initial_loading_screen) return <InitialRender />

        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                <EditorView
                    data={this.state.data}
                    section_headers={['', '', 'Job', 'Certification']}
                    section_titles={['Title Block', 'Skills Block', 'Work Experience', 'Education Block']}
                />

                <div className='button-group'>
                    <button type='submit' className='btn btn-outline-primary active'>Submit</button>
                    <button type='submit' name='render' className='btn btn-outline-primary'>Render</button>
                    <button type='reset' className='btn btn-outline-primary'>Cancel</button>
                    <button type='button' className='btn btn-outline-primary'>Editor</button>

                    <div className='button-group__view'>
                        <button type='button' onClick={() => window.open('/resume/render')} className='btn btn-primary'>View</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
```

Now I am not posting this as a code review. Tips and pointers would be appreciated, but not necessary. In my inherited class, I initialize my state values and customize my render. For this example class, I am rendering a resume form; and in other classes, I am rendering a similar form but will have different state values and renders.

My question then, is if the approach I am using in the correct direction, or due to my inexperience with React (and web development in general), a more robust method that I am unaware of?

Comment: My first question in reading this is *why?* What is the inheritance adding that you couldn't easily accomplish with a single component? (Or a single function) Inheritance comes at a cost: complexity. Just trying to figure out what this code does requires repeatedly switching back and forth between the two classes. This is a burden on the reader and good code is readable code. I'd write this as a single component and avoid class inheritance altogether in React. This is object-oriented inspired, but React is much better suited for functional programming.

Comment: I found myself rewriting the same basic class with minor changes. There would be some variation, but I decided to generalize the core of what I needed in a parent, then let the children specialize.

Comment: To elaborate more, I did have a single component originally, but it started to become too complex. So then I started to make separate components and make the code more compartmentalized. But changing a line in one component meant changing it in others... Finally, it's easier for me to have the parent on one screen and the child on other rather than scrolling through a large single component. @CharlieMartin

Comment: You're really overthinking this.  If each form is similar in style (HTML structure, validation logic, error handling, etc), simply manage all the state variations in a global state manager like context or redux, and distribute the pertinent state to some generic form component.  Have some flag to determine which form requires what state (probably from the parent container the form resides in) and enjoy modularity.

Comment: EDIT:  You could also bypass the global state idea and funnel every input through some imported utility handlers.  Differentiate through arguments and manage state this way.

Comment: @AttemptedMastery Thank you. I realized I was over thinking this. I have a couple of functional components in my app that  hook in with props. For whatever reason, I never thought to pass props into my main component i.e. `<StandardComponent props={foo} />` So there was no reason for me to use an OOP approach. Doing some more research, I realized why I couldn't find any tutorials for inheritance -- it's ultimately bad practice and highly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with class components, but I'd recommend learning functional components. Class components are slowly being faded out. I can't answer your question but just wanna prevent you from having to relearn something a different way.

Comment: Thank you. I've looked into functional components, but a lot of the tutorials I've used tended to have class components, so I decided to practice using them. Then once I have what I want working, transition to functional components.

Answer (score 0):

### Don't inherit, use combination instead

You can read the guide from react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)